# Haskell map/zip Vs. list comprehension

Tags: haskell, zip, list-comprehension, pointfree, combinators

Which of the following are you most likely to write?

```
r = zip xs $ map sqrt xs
```

or

```
r = [(x, sqrt x) | x <- xs]
```

Sample code on the Internet seems to indicate that the former is more abundant and the preferred way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd likely write

```
map (\x -> (x, sqrt x)) xs
```

If you prefer point-free, the above is equivalent to (after having imported `Control.Monad` and `Control.Monad.Instances`)

```
map (ap (,) sqrt) xs
```

Another alternative that hasn't yet been mentioned is

```
zipWith (,) xs (map sqrt xs)
```

Answer (score 27):

People who spend too much time in #haskell would probably write that as

```
r = map (id &&& sqrt) xs
```

`(&&&)` is a fun combinator defined in `Control.Arrow`.  Its actual type signature is complicated because it's generalized to all instances of Arrow.  But it's often used with the `(->)` instance of `Arrow`, which results in this type signature:

```
(&&&) :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> a -> (b, c)
```

Comment: I refer to this as "opaque haskell".

At a certain point it's just illegible, the point varies on exposure.

Comment: In fact, I tend to define a function which, for lack of a better name, I call `preserving :: (a -> b) -> a -> (a,b)`, defined as simply `preserving = (id &&&)`.  (Sometimes I also swap the tuple order and define it as `(&&& id)`; I ought to be consistent.)  I'm always a little surprised that it doesn't seem to exit anywhere standard.

Comment: Dan, I think that's probably the easiest Arrow combinator to use in real code.  Its name is nicely evocative: you can read that line of code out loud as "map id and sqrt to xs".

Comment: I agree, I think this is very readable. It does force readers to learn what `&&&` does, but that's fun :-).

Answer (score 18):

Although I tend not to use them very often, in this case, I think I'd prefer the list comprehension version, since it seems cleaner to me.

If you're into point free style, you might like this one, too:

```
f = zip `ap` map sqrt
```

`ap` lives in Control.Monad and in this case, it can be thought of as the S combinator, which generalizes application in [SKI calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic):

```
ap f g x == f x (g x)
ap const const == id
```

As Conal points out, this may also be generalized from Monad to Applicative thus (`import Control.Applicative`):

```
f = zip <*> map sqrt
```

Comment: nice, I like that notation the best. I always read `ap` as "apply", so it becomes: "zip apply map with sqrt to input"

Comment: Or, simplifying/generalizing from `Monad` to `Applicative`, `f = zip <*> map sqrt`.

Though I personally prefer `map (id &&& sqrt) xs` as in carl's answer.

Comment: Yes, that's IMHO a nice way to read it. @Conal added your suggestion to the answer.

Answer (score 13):

I would probably write `map`/`zip` and then later wish I had written the list comprehension.

Answer (score 11):

For certain types of problems ([Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) in particular), this particular case comes up so often that I wrote the following little helper:

```
with :: (a -> b) -> a -> (a,b)
with f a = (a, f a)
```

This allows your example to be written:

```
r = map (with sqrt) xs
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm more of an "Old School" Haskellier, so I'd use `` zip `ap` map sqrt `` and later refactor it to use the `<*>` instead of `ap`.

Applicative is the new Monad. (In the sense of "what do the Cool Haskell Kids use these days?")

Comment: arrows are the new monad, no?

Answer (score 7):

I rarely use list comprehensions, but both are dandy. Just use the one that makes your code easier to read.